# How to execute all Android JUnit tests in Appcenter post-build script

Tags: android, gradlew, visual-studio-app-center

I am new to Android builds with AppCenter and wish to execute all my Apps JUnits.

My app consists of multiple modules that each have their associated JUnits.

However my main App module has no JUnits.

I've tried creating an `appcenter-post-build.sh` script to execute command `./gradlew test`

which fails as follows:-

```
[command]/bin/bash /Users/runner/work/1/s/app/appcenter-post-build.sh
/Users/runner/work/1/s/app/appcenter-post-build.sh: line 5: ./gradlew: No such file or directory

##[error]The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 127
##[error]Bash failed with error: The process '/bin/bash' failed with exit code 127
```

is there any way I can execute all my Apps modules JUnits via a post build script?

Answer (score 0):

try to add this in your shell script.

```
cd $APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY
chmod a+x ./gradlew
```